How to extract selected values from json string in Hive into columns dynamically
I have data as below
+------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|asset_id                |json                                                                                                                                              |
+------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1234                    |{"CRC":{"SC":"CATS>1","daterange":"6"},"BLM":{"name":"RSPCA","daterange":"24"}}                                                                   |
+------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1235                    |{"CRC":{"VC":"BLUERUSSIAN,BURMESE,PERSIAN>0","daterange":"12"},"BLM":{"name":"RSPCA","daterange":"24"}}                                           |
+------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1236                    |{"CSC":{"SC":"BLUERUSSIAN>0;BURMESE<=10","daterange":"3"},"FSC":{"BLCS":"BATC"},"BPCC":{"targetBPCs":"931134535316,931134535317,931134535318"}}   |
+------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

How can I dynamically spit the json out into individual columns?
Expected results as below:
+------------------------+-----------+---------------------------------+---------------+----------------+--------------+------------------+----------------+--------------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
|asset_id                |CRC.SC     | CRC.VC                          |CRC.daterange  |CSC.SC_1        |CSC.SC_2      |CSC.daterange     |FSC.BLCS        |BPCC.targetBPCs                       |BLM.name        |BLM.daterange  |
+------------------------+-----------+---------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------+------------------+----------------+--------------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
|1234                    |CATS>1     |                                 |6              |                |              |                  |                |                                      |RSPCA           |24             |
+------------------------+-----------+---------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------+------------------+----------------+--------------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
|1235                    |           |BLUERUSSIAN,BURMESE,PERSIAN>0    |12             |                |              |                  |                |                                      |RSPCA           |24             |
+------------------------+-----------+---------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------+------------------+----------------+--------------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
|1236                    |           |                                 |               |BLUERUSSIAN>0   |BURMESE<=10   |3                 |BATC            |931134535316,931134535317,931134535318|                |               |               
+------------------------+-----------+---------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------+------------------+----------------+--------------------------------------+----------------+---------------+

